# Keep the domain object field unsaved, but still be read from DB using Grails ORM

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I have a Grails domain object called `User` and among it other fields it has the following SQL column definition

```
`last_modified_in_db` timestamp NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
```

So this field gets automatically updated on every `save()` operation I perform on this domain object.

I need to read this property in my app, so I add `lastModifiedInDb` property for this domain object and it works great, until I try to save this object. When I do, then `last_modified_in_db` column does not get updated. So I need to make this field `transient` for write operations only. Any way I can do this?

Answer (score 0):

I'm also planing to use something like this.
I found (but not yet tested):

```
static mapping = {
  author insertable: false
  author updateable: false
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As soon as your property is read-only, you can use formula:

```
static mapping = {
   lastModifiedInDb formula:'last_modified_in_db'
}
```